# Why is Svelte invalidating a variable that isn't changed?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have a Svelte component that allows editing a list of strings, with the list coming from the writable store $places.  This is displayed in the web UI as a list of  tags, one longer than the list of places (so that people can add to the list).

```js
let inputs: string[] = []
$: {
  inputs = [...$places, '']
}
```

The web code renders as follows:

```html
<label for="place0">Places</label>
{#each inputs as input, idx}
  <input id="place{idx}" name="places" type="text" bind:value={input} />
{/each}
```

For some reason I can't understand, any attempt to type in these input fields causes Svelte to assume that both `inputs` and `$places` have been invalidated.  Because it thinks `$places` has been invalidated, the first code block above gets triggered, essentially overriding whatever the user was trying to type and making the field effectively read-only.

I have verified this behavior looking at the compiled code:

```js
function input_input_handler(each_value, idx) {
  each_value[idx] = this.value;
  $$invalidate(0, inputs), $$invalidate(1, $places);
}
```

As you can see, the last line marks both `inputs` and `$places` as invalidated.  I can't see any reason why `$places` should be invalidated, and it's breaking my component.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to prevent or circumvent it?  Many thanks....

Comment: Re why: it's apparently a (confusing) implementation detail: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4933#issuecomment-1383940183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...how to prevent or circumvent it

If `$places` is already initialized when the component is mounted, no reactive statement would be needed and just `let inputs = [...$places, '']` would work

If `$places` might not yet be set, a subscription could be used instead of the `$:` reactive statement [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/20d9d96996f747c781b9302814ad8304?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>
    import {places} from './places'
        
    let inputs = []

    const unsubPlaces = places.subscribe($places => inputs = [...$places, '']) // unsub in onDestroy()
</script>

{#each inputs as input, idx}
<input id="place{idx}" name="places" type="text" bind:value={input} />
{/each}
```

or

```
<script>
    import {places} from './places'
        
    let inputs = []
    
    $: $places, initInputs()
    
    function initInputs() {
         inputs = [...$places, '']
    }
</script>

{#each inputs as input, idx}
<input id="place{idx}" name="places" type="text" bind:value={input} />
{/each}
```

Like this all values are stored inside `inputs`, based on `$places` but with no 'backward connection'.

With H.B.'s answer the input values are split and the `$places` ones are still connected to the store plus the seperate new one stored in `inputs`. Depends on how you need and want to handle the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is done, so that any other code that uses the array gets updated when any of the items change.

The problem is that you use a reactive statement (`$:`) to radically alter state. If you want to add one empty item, just do it once or separate inputs from other data.

You can extract the content of the loop into a component and just split the loop like this:

```html
<script>
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
    import Input from './Input.svelte';

    const places = writable(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    const inputs = [''];
</script>

{#each $places as place, idx}
  <Input {idx} bind:value={place} />
{/each}
{#each inputs as input, idx}
  <Input {idx} bind:value={input} />
{/each}
```

(In the future it might be possible to declare the component inline, so it is not necessary to create a separate file for this.)

[REPL Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/5a2c9fb55084409ebbb35cead6b85f80?version=3.48.0)

Comment: Using the index as key inside the #each loop can't work, can it? Doing `{#each things as thing, index (index)}` in the tutorial https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks doesn't

Comment: @Corrl I think it's pretty redundant, i.e. identical to not having a key, going to remove it...

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand.  There is no code in my entire file that makes any assignment to $places.  Certainly the <input> control doesn't.  According to the docs, the only things that are invalidated are the ones to which there is an explicit assignment.  So, *why* is $places being invalidated?

Comment: I don't really understand the 'why' as well... why does it behave differently in the first case, when the store value is an array? https://svelte.dev/repl/7d26653c05da4f098ecc776d1b0c4aec?version=3.48.0

Comment: @rothskeller: Svelte will always invalidate the entire known hierarchy. E.g. if you bind to `obj.child.value`, it will invalidate `obj`. This way if `obj` is passed into another component and there `child` or its `value` are used, the changes will propagate correctly. [Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/db55e36508f6480c841637622704b588?version=3.48.0)

Comment: @Corrl: If an item in the array is modified, the array is invalidated. (See also my previous comment.)

Comment: (Invalidated primitives only cause reactive changes if the value is different, for objects this is not the case.)